# Display error if user enters only spaces in EditText - Android

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I want to show error if user only enters spaces in EditText but i don't know how?

Here is my simple work

```
if (tName.getText().toString().matches(" ")) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Must Add Your Name Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Check `if (tName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") == false)`

Comment: If you need your user to input only text and numbers in the edittext you can use `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"`. EditText will not accept any other characters except those mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for me i use trim.Trim will remove first and last space of a string entered by a user.

```
String tName = tName.getText().toString.trim();

if(tName.matches("")){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Must Add Your Name Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: im glad that it helps you. :D

Answer (score 3):

Try with this code

```
 if(!editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
           editText.setError("Empty spaces are not allowed");
           editText.setFocusable(true);
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Must Add Your Name Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following code.

```
String name = tName.getText().toString();
if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()){
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name"+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Must Add Your Name Here",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to check white space in `Edittext`

```
string name = "Paul Creasey";//edittext.gettext.tostring();
if (name.contains(" ")) {
//use this to show any msg
}
```

Comment: this will only show till one or two blank spaces after that it will not

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(tName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
//your code for handing white space
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String strName = tName.getText().toString().trim();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strName)) {
                tName.setError("Enter Your Name");
                return;
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

This solution also makes my field `mandatory` like "Must add your name here", In my case, I am looking for a solution where I have a name field but I only want to restrict the user from entering empty spaces however it's up to them whether they want to fill their name or not but they can't enter empty spaces.

So below code works for me

```
 public static boolean checkForEmptySpaces(String value){
    if (value.length()>0 && value.trim().matches("")) {
             showToast(v.getContext(), "Empty spaces are not allowed!");
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```